# Do we really need the [stanford] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I have edited a question when I looked at the tags it appeared [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) tag, in the description it says:

> Stanford University is a research university located in Palo Alto, CA.

So... I guess it's not a programming related tag.

I mean, who can be an expert in such a tag?

Comment: There are plenty of usages where it simply needs to be replaced by [tag:stanford-nlp] (or removed because it already contains that tag). In other cases, it probably needs to be replaced by more specific tags or simply removed.

Comment: It's also often used for tagging questions about their CS course homework (e.g. CS106A). It's not a useful tag in that context either.

Comment: Editors, please be careful retagging. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10766942/revisions), for example, is not about [standford-nlp].

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514882/cs107-assignment-files) isn't, either.

Comment: @AndrewMedico And reviewers, please be careful while approving.

Comment: @frakcool - found your expert: http://siextramustard.files.wordpress.com/2014/02/stanford-tree13.jpg

Comment: [status-complete]. Now we wait for it to burn itself.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Indeed, [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) is not a good tag. It could be applied to anything related to Stanford University. The fact that a question has some connection with Stanford University is not relevant. This tag should be removed, and possibly replaced by relevant good tags such as [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp).

Don't blindly replace [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) by [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp), only when the latter tag is applicable! For example [c++ vector compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21802117/c-vector-compilation-error) isn't about Stanford JavaNLP.

As always, while you're doing this, please fix anything else that should be fixed: other tags, spelling, formatting, title, etc.

Comment: There are about 30 posts left. Just to be sure, if the question is about a Stanford lecture, then just delete the tag?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, the fact that a post is motivated by a Stanford lecture doesn't warrant a tag. Just delete the tag (and fix anything else that you see that needs fixing).

Comment: Why would you delete a possibly useful way of filtering information?

Comment: @LukeStanley How is it useful to filter information based on “has some connection with Stanford University”? Besides, it can be done by a full-text search.

Comment: <snark>It is extremely useful to future CS students at Stanford University looking to cheat on their homework. It's like a free online solution manual!</snark>

Comment: IMHO, this tag is as helpful as "programming", "player", or "item" would be.. IF the people out there really need such tag to mark (housekeep?)questions/answers regarding their lectures, then maybe they should simply form a new micro-stack-site dedicated to that?

Comment: Renaming is one thing but deleting is different.They might have meant something else, in which case ambiguity resolution is helpful.Let's imagine this deletion policy in a different domain: For everyone Googling something to do with Standford, let's say the term Standford was ignored: do you think that would HELP them find what they are looking for? Deletion tags suggests you don't see the benefit in tags. They are non-exclusive metadata that's easy and helpful in unpredictable situations. Just because you can't see how it's useful to the person who put it there doesn't mean it isn't.  @Gilles

Comment: Maybe instead of a micro-stack-site, it would be easier if people could use tags or something? @quetzalcoatl

Comment: @LukeStanley Full-text search is not the same thing as categorizing. That's the whole reason for having more than full-text search. Categorizing strives to use meaningful categories. If [tag:stanford] is used, say, to mean “this is homework given in a class at Stanford”, this is bad, because exactly the same question from a Berkeley student would have a different tag even though the information would be exactly the same.

Comment: Of course it's not the same thing, but the point is you seemed to be suggesting deleting information was a good thing, thus reducing ability to search or filter correctly. That's not a problem as such @Gilles - in that scenario, someone could add a Berkeley tag, if such a thing were a good idea in principle.