# What constitutes "Too Minor" when it comes to tag editing?

Tags: discussion, tags, suggested-edits

The last couple of days, I've seen a lot of questions roll through the *Suggested Edits* queue where the only change made was adding/removing a tag. Most of the times, the suggested edit is adding a tag that may be slightly more descriptive, but not enough to really impact the question.

In some cases, I can see where it is warranted. [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3528562/zoyd?tab=reputation), for example, was changing the [edt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/edt) tag (which was actually an incorrect tag in most cases) to the more relevant [event-dispatch-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/event-dispatch-thread) tag. This seems legitimate.

However, today the *Suggested Review* queue has been filled with questions where [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180785/frakcool?tab=reputation) removed the [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) tag and replaced it with the [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) tag. This doesn't seem to change/benefit the question in any real way and seemed too small, so I rejected most of them. I seemed to be in the minority though because most of them were approved, as noted by the 193 rep points earned today through edits. In [one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21802117/revisions) particular case, the same user made an invalid edit, gained +2 rep, had the edit rolled back, made an additional edit, which again would appear to be "too minor", had it approved and gained an additional +2 rep having not really contributed any context or benefit toward the question.

So my question is, when is it considered "too minor" in terms of tag edits? I know the reputation gained in this case is not much in the grand scheme of things, but it would appear that the user is gaining rep because reviewers aren't really considering the entire edit and how it affects the context of the question (i.e. the reviewers don't appear to be noting whether the edit "substantially improves the post").

I just want to note that I'm not complaining. I just want to learn for my benefit. It is quite possible my rejections were wrong, in which case I would like to understand the reasoning behind why I should accept what appears to be minor edits. My objective here is that of learning how to correctly respond to such edits.

**EDIT:**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9492098/revisions) is another such case of an invalid edit approved twice with +4 rep by the same user.

Comment: Your evaluations are entirely correct.  You seem to have a very good understanding of how to evaluate the value of an edit.  You have also correctly observed that the *vast* majority of suggested edit reviewers have virtually *no* ability to evaluate the value of edits (or worse still, the validity of edits) and tend to approve most everything.  This is extremely depressing.  I wish I had a solution for you.  I've been searching for one for years.

Comment: tl;dr: The same "too minor" rule applies to tag-only edits.  If there are other things that could be improved in the question, especially *obvious* things, then the edit is too minor, even if it's otherwise valid and helpful.  **Never forget about the "Improve" button!**  Just uncheck the "this was helpful" checkbox at the bottom.

Comment: See also: [Do we really need the \[stanford\] tag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255938/168868)

Comment: @Servy I agree 100%. That's what I was thinking as well. This is not so much a problem with the user as it is a learning/obeservation problem with the reviewers. If the reviewers didn't accept such edits, the user would never be able go on a tagging rampage of sorts. This would, in essence, help the user understand his/her mistake and be able to correct the incorrect edit actions with more appropriate and substantial edits. Maybe the review screens could bold/italicize the important key words such as ***substantial*** so that the reviewers would take a closer look? Just a thought...

Comment: @War10ck I doubt that that would make a difference, personally.  I am regularly surprised by the level of incompetence in suggested edit reviewers.  Somehow the bar always manages to be lowered.

Comment: @Servy Unfortunately, I'm starting to observe the same trend. It seems much too easy to hit accept and move on without really focusing on the task at hand. It seems it is becoming more of a review game for badges than for cleaning and managing the site...

Comment: @War10ck Of course, the fact that there is a [proposed] tag cleanup request for that tag in no way makes these edits appropriate.  it explains them, but it doesn't validate them.  Tag cleanup guidelines very explicitly make it clear that edits should be significant, they should be making meaningful improvements to the post at hand, and fixing all of the problems with the post, not just removing the one tag.  This user is clearly violating that, so the existence of a tag cleanup request doesn't make the edit automatically good.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Too minor" edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253326/too-minor-edits-better-to-leave-poor-quality-on-the-site)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) is not a good tag. It could be applied to anything related to Stanford University. The fact that a question has some connection with Stanford University is not relevant.

[stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) designates a particular programming environment (a suite of libraries). It's a perfectly normal tag with a clear meaning.

Getting rid of the [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) and replacing it by an appropriate tag such as [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) is a good, encouraged edit. Removing a bad tag does not qualify as “too minor”. It's always better to fix anything else that should be fixed (other tags, spelling, formatting, title, etc.), but even an edit which just replaces [stanford](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford) by a more appropriate tag is good.

Approve the edit if it replaces the bad tag by good ones. Reject it if it replaces the bad tag with other bad tags (e.g. if it incorrectly adds [stanford-nlp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stanford-nlp) to a question that's related to Stanford but not to the Stanford NLP Java library suite.

Comment: Yes, actually removing just one bad tag and doing nothing else for a post *absolutely* qualifies as "too minor".  It's the *epitome* of too minor.  There is nothing *less* useful that you could do in an edit than just remove a useless tag.  If all we wanted to do was remove the tag from every question it was tagged with then that could simply be done by a developer running a script.  The whole *point* of tag cleanups is that we *don't* want to do that.  The idea of a tag cleanup is to be *dramatically* improving posts by fixing all of the problems with them, not just removing one tag.

Comment: I definitely agree that the [tag:stanford] needs cleaning. However, I have to wonder if that really qualifies as a _good edit_. As @Servy has pointed out, it really doesn't contribute in any significant way to the post. It's my understanding that an edit should. If I understand correctly, an edit should improve the meaning, readability, formatting or other related aspect of the question, without altering the original author's context of the question or the problem as it was originally defined.

Comment: @Servy No, removing one bad tag is not intrinsically too minor. We need to get rid of that tag. If there are posts which are fine except for that one bad tag, how would we ever get rid of that tag if we were not to edit posts because it's “too minor”?

Comment: @Gilles You would have a developer run a script to remove the tag from all of the posts that its on.  Having users who don't need to *suggest* edits remove the tag is also an option, if the number of tagged questions is sufficiently small.

Comment: @Servy An automatic cleanup is only possible on a superfluous tag. [tag:stanford] isn't superfluous, it's ambiguous: it sometimes means [tag:stanford-nlp], maybe sometimes other things (I haven't checked), and sometimes it's superfluous. This requires manual cleanup. Given that there's no lack of manpower for the suggested edit review queue these days, if an edit is worth doing unsupervised, it's worth suggesting.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, so the fact that this user is going around removing the tag from all questions it's on *and doing nothing else* is **actively harmful**.  It's not even *useless* it's *wrong*.  This user *isn't* fixing tag ambiguities, he's just removing the tag from every question that it's on and almost never doing anything else.  An effective tag cleanup would be to go through and resolve the ambiguities by ensuring the appropriate tags were added where needed, questions closed where offtopic, etc., and then a mass automatic removal of all remaining superfluous taggings.

Comment: And after spending some time looking a bit further back through this user's history, there are a number of times where he's incorrectly adding the standford-nlp tag to questions it doesn't apply to.  a *huge* percentage of his taggings are actually invalid, despite the fact that virtually none managed to actually get rejected.

Comment: @Servy In that case the correct rejection reason is *invalid*, not *too minor*.

Comment: @Gilles There are a lot of both in there, not just one or the other.  *Just* removing standford is "too minor".  Incorrectly applying standord-nlp is *invalid*.  He has done a lot of both.

Comment: @Servy No, just removing [tag:stanford] if that is the only obvious problem with the question is not too minor. “Too minor” means “you're wasting time with a useless edit”. If the edit is useful, it isn't too minor.

Comment: @Gilles It's absolutely a useless edit.  It is adding *zero* value to the site.  *Nobody* is better off as a result of that edit.  As I said, there is no possible edit that you could make that adds *less* value.  The tag itself is inherently useless in that it doesn't help anyone find or categorize the question.  Having it there adds no value.  It's not really actively harmful though, so removing it doesn't add value either.  However if a C question is tagged C++ that tag is *actively harmful*, possibly even to a significant degree, and removing the incorrect tag is *adding* value.

Comment: @Servy The tag still needs to be removed. So removing it is not “actively harmful”. (I haven't checked that user's edit history; if he's going around adding [tag:standford-nlp] where it doesn't belong, then *that* is actively harmful. But removing [tag:stanford] isn't.)

Comment: @Gilles Removing the tag and doing nothing else when the post is in need of other edits, such as, for example, the addition of the stanford-nlp tag, *is* actively harmful.  It goes from being actively harmful to just too minor if the tags use is truly superfluous, and not ambiguous.

Comment: @Servy: Gilles and I disagree about pretty much everything, but I'm squarely in his camp on this one.  The question you have to ask yourself is this: *Is the tag change important enough that you would have made it yourself?*  To put it another way, are you obligated as an editor to *fix every problem with every post that has that tag* to get the tag burninated?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Should you not be asking yourself if the edit that you are suggesting is adding more value than the cost of suggesting the edit?  If we have a problem in the site's ability to burninate tags (which I'm not sure that we do) then we can look at improved tooling around tag burnination, rather than applying a solution to a problem that causes more harm than the problem itself.

Comment: @Servy: That's a legitimate question.  But if it doesn't hit threshold for you, then don't expect suggested editors to *ever* help you with burnination requests.  Improved tooling doesn't seem like it's on the horizon at this point; I think SE wants there to be some friction in the process.

Comment: @RobertHarvey In my experiences 1) most tag cleanups tend to be done by 2k+ users, not through suggested edits, indicating that there isn't a *need* for suggested edits to help with burnination requests 2) when I *do* see suggested edits working on burnination requests they're usually more harmful than helpful, as the end up being of the "remove this tag and don't even look at anything else" variety, which as I said, is *actively harmful* to a tag cleanup.  I see so few quality tag cleanup contributions from suggested editors that I don't see a compelling need to actively try to involve them.

Comment: @Servy: Fair enough.  I personally think that tag cleanups shouldn't have to involve the wholesale cleaning of the posts themselves.  I should be able to push a button and remove the Stanford tag.  Boom.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I personally agree with the mentality that it's good to have some friction in there and to not make it too easy to have someone push a button and have a tag go poof.  But at the same time, if "tag cleanups" end up being nothing but 1-2 users going and suggesting a few hundred edits doing nothing but removing a tag *what value was added* there over just having one person press a button an poofing away the tag?

Comment: @Servy: That's fine.  But I wonder about the wisdom of some folks constantly posting legitimate burnination requests, in an effort to get an improved tag surface.  The friction currently involved makes it equivalent to bailing a sinking Spanish galleon with a teacup.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've thought that myself on a number of occasions.

Comment: @Servy In my experience, a lot of sub-2k users are involved in tag cleanups. Even sub-500 (which used to be the threshold for tag edits). While useless tags could be removed by a button press (and sometimes are), ambiguous tags have to be handled manually. The value of doing it manually is that sometimes the tag needs to be removed, and sometimes it needs to be replaced by something else. Removing it where it should be removed is a valid edit.

Comment: @Gilles But that's just it.  Whenever I see suggested editors doing tag cleanups, such as in this case (and even for a fair number of 2k+ users) they *don't* evaluate the post to see if new tags should replace the existing ones, if it should be removed, *which* new tags should be added, etc.  They either blindly replace one tag with another or blindly remove it.  This user *isn't* doing what you're saying that he should be doing, and I don't see suggested editors ever doing what you say they should be.

Comment: @Servy So when they aren't doing what should be done (adding an inapplicable tag or not adding a tag that should be there), reject as *invalid*.

Comment: @Gilles Of course *that doesn't happen* because *reviewers don't actually review suggested edits*.  The end result is that they accept all of them, no matter what, even though the vast majority of them are invalid.  And just to be clear, I'm not saying that your much lower bar for quality of edits is good enough.  I'm saying that the editors out there don't even reach your bar of quality which is *still too low*.