# When a tag clearly falls under another tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, questions

This is a multi-part question, but all parts are about the same general subject: tags that 100% of the time imply another, additional broader tag. I usually frequent the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, but I've definitely missed stuff that I can/want to help with because it doesn't actually have the broad tag. In fact the other day I lucked into a bounty on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19967244/turn-off-logback-logging-for-other-libraries-while-in-certain-class/23810138#23810138)... and the only reason I **ever** saw it is because it had a bounty. However, I think it is a great question and I definitely would have seen it earlier if it had the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag, which is why I edited those tags into it later.

### 1. Is it an appropriate edit to add these tags?

Say I find a question with one tag: [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane). This will 100% of the time mean the user is writing a [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) application in [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing). **Should I be adding these tags in?** Note that I have over 2000 rep so this is not about "suggested edits"... but:

### 2. If it's yes for me to add these tags in, what about users with less than 2000 rep?

It could be too minor... but it might not be. Though this sub-question is sort of a [duplicate of this question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255951/what-constitutes-too-minor-when-it-comes-to-tag-editing)

### 3. Maybe some tags should *automatically* add these outer tags?

This would help new users to sort questions when they don't realize how important/widely used the tag system is. It could also help to break the five tag limit on questions that merge multiple technologies, while **still** filing them under the broad headings. This could be done in two ways:

1. Broad tags are added silently, and are kept in a separate category. Only the **most specific** tag will be counted against the 5 tag limit. Here's what I mean via examples:

   - User creates a post with three tags, [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing), [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane).

     - The [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) tags are automatically converted to category tags, and the post only has one tag that counts against the 5 tag limit, but the post will appear under all three tags.
   - User creates a post with one tag, [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane)

     - This post will automatically add the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) category tags, so the post will be tagged exactly as the previous example.
   - User creates a post with one tag, [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)

     - This post will automatically add the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag as a category tag, but in this example [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) WILL count against the 5 tag limit.
2. Alternately, tags could be automatically added **if and only if** the post has fewer than 5 tags.

   - User creates a post with [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane)

     - Post automatically becomes tagged [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing), [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane), exactly as we see it today.
   - User creates a post with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java), [jscrollpane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jscrollpane), [mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql), [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database), [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql).

     - If the post did not have 5 tags, [swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing) would be automatically added. However, because it does have 5 tags already, nothing happens.

Comment: Poor tagging is a strong selector for poor questions.  Automatically fixing this and exposing poor questions to *thousands* of SO users instead of dozens is not what SO needs.  Listen to the last podcast for background info.

Comment: @HansPassant strong selector for poor questions or for new users?

Comment: Well, 2 minutes wasn't enough to listen to that podcast.  New users were discussed as well.

Comment: Recent similar discussion with links to many previous related discussions: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255245/simple-tag-hierarchy-to-aid-in-searching-browsing