# If one tag implies another, should I still use both?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that both [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) questions are also tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).

However, as [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) is a library for CPython, this is implicitly obvious.  *Any* numpy question is also a Python question.

Should I then use both tags, or only [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy)?

([This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256787/974555) is closely related, but specifically asks if one should *edit* other questions for this.  My question is about tagging when I'm asking my question in the first place.)

Comment: Hmm, I'm considering closing this as a dupe of the question you linked. Editing is about improving posts. If the community decides that broader tags should be edited in, there's no reason to not do it from the start. Likewise, if the community decides they should not be edited in / should be edited out, there's no reason to do it from the start.

Comment: @Stijn Except that some edits may be [considered too minor](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255951/what-constitutes-too-minor-when-it-comes-to-tag-editing?rq=1).

Comment: While this is logically true, if people only look at the `python` tag for unanswered questions, then a `numpy` only tagged question will receive less visibility.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255245/simple-tag-hierarchy-to-aid-in-searching-browsing) and/or the various linked discussions.  In short, the majority view is that it is up to the poster to include all tags that might help find the right people to answer the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always include a programming language tag.  Many folks just monitor the Python tag for new questions.

Comment: Do my eyes deceive or has my comment been thieved!?!

Comment: Answers are always preferable.  If they're answers.

Comment: I'm hesitant to post answers (or questions) on Meta. Previous attempts have been met with "His rep is a rounding error; SEIZE HIM!!".

Comment: @dilbert: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rBAwl.jpg