# Should I use both tags - java and java-8

Tags: discussion, tags

I see that some questions on Stack Overflow are tagged with [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) but lack the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag. For me personally this has lead to me missing out on some of the [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) questions before realizing this (now I follow both tags).

According to this answer - [If one tag implies another, should I still use both?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258113/if-one-tag-implies-another-should-i-still-use-both) - the accepted answer suggests that you should *Always include a programming language tag* but [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) is also a programming language tag.

So, when tagging a question as [java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8) - should you always include the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag as well?

Comment: I think there was a similar question some time ago about [tag:c++] and [tag:c++11]. In short: use the general tag because this is what most people follow (in their favorite tags), but specify the version when your question applies to that version of the language specifically.

Comment: I'd tag it even if the question didn't apply to that version specifically or you'd run the risk of getting answers that does.

Comment: Excellent, Martijn Pieters found a duplicate [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version). The short answer is - add the `java` tag as well.